# copy clone trigger img to another element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using this [owl carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/) with [easyzoom](https://i-like-robots.github.io/EasyZoom/). when I enter the photo, that photo zooms in.

[image]

When moving in the photo with the mouse and the position of the photo changes (x,y)
Copy the element immediately. I want to copy that zoomed image to another element.

**js:**

```
$('body .tumb-posi img').attr('style', $('body .tumb-posi img').attr('style') + ';' +$('.easyzoom-flyout img').attr('style'));
```

**out:**

```
<div class="tumb-posi"><img style="undefined;undefined"></div>
```

When it wants to copy, it sends as **undefined**.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/behrouzbash/b3kmdjr1/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run this every time the mouse moves:

```
$("#owl-demo").on("mousemove", ".easyzoom-flyout", function() {
  var el = $('.easyzoom-flyout img');
  $('.tumb-posi img').attr('src', el.attr("src"));
  $('.tumb-posi img').attr('style', el.attr("style"));
});
```

Updated demo: https://jsfiddle.net/bortao/fy3ev6q4/